# Subclass/ Superclass Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm learning Objective-C, noob question.

I'm working on a project in Xcode that requires multiple geometric object-types (square, triangle, etc). Each object file is made a subclass of the superclass "GraphicObject," for which there is a file as well obviously.

My question is, when I create a new file to contain main code body, I cannot seem to make the new file recognize the subclasses of GraphicObject unless I do this:

#import "GraphicObject.h"

#import "Rectangle.h"

#import "Triangle.h"

#import "Circle.h"

#import "Square.h"

Is there a way for me to have the file refer to all subclasses of the GraphicObject class without explicitly adding them via the #import function?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are confusing subclasses and dependencies. Just because `Rectangle` inherits from `GraphicObject`, the class that uses just `GraphicObject` has no idea what `Rectangle` is. You would need to use all of those `#imports`.